# Turning multiple plots into an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, simulation

I've written a function that calculates the electric field due to N charges and then plots it. The function is the following:

```
def plotE(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,charge,position,a):
    """
    Args:
        xmin (float): minimum x value of chart.
        xmax (float): maximum x value of chart.
        ymin...
        ymax...
        charge (array of float): array of charges
        position (iterable of float): (x, y) position(s) of the point charge(s).
            If an array is given, it should be a (2, N) array where N
            is the number of point charges.
        a: number of vectors in each row and column
        
    """
    code goes here
```

The plots are done using the matplotlib quiver function and looks something like this:
[image]

I also have another function that continuously updates the positions of the particles and stores the positions in arrays. So, if I had 2 particles, I would have 4 arrays with the x position of particle 1, y position of particle 1, x position of particle 2, and y position of particle 2. I also have a final array which is the time, which has the same length as the position arrays.

I am wondering how I can turn this into an animation. For each element in the time array, say time[i], I want to plot x1[i], y1[i], x2[i], y2[i]. I also want to use my electric field function above with the current particle positions to draw the little arrows in the background.

Currently, I can easily make a single plot using t[i], x1[i], y1[i], ..., and the plotE function. In theory, if I repeatedly do this say 100 times for i=0,2,3,...99, I'll get 100 plots. If I then play the 100 images back to back, I get an animation. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Comment: There are many examples of animating plots on SO, and you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and show your effort.

Comment: all animations work as you described - they plays N-images one-by-one with small delay. You can use own loop for this. But some tools may have function to make life easier. Matplotlib has `FunAnimation` to run your function every few milliseconds and this function should calculate data for new plot and replace them on old plot. If you use Google then you should find many examples - even in Matplotlib documentation.